# I made a game with Ruby, How do I make it playable on the internet?[Ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

It is a very simple game, only consisting of about 80 lines of code, and 2 images. I am a new developer, so pardon my ignorance.
I uploaded the three files to a domain, but when I visit the location, it just downloads the file.
What do I need to do in order to have the file be executed opposed to just downloaded? What other information is relevant to running it as a 'web app'?
Thanks

Comment: Is this game in just pure Ruby, or did you write it in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Just Ruby with Gosu and chipmunk gem

Comment: That is why your game is just downloading instead of being a web app. You wrote a desktop app, you didn't write a web app. If you like Ruby, then I suggest looking into Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your input

Comment: By _"playable on the internet"_ you probably mean in a browser. Can you run it locally in a browser?

Answer (score 3):

If you're written a console application (which it sounds like you have) then you will not be able to run it on the web. Depending on what you've made you may be able to translate it into a web application using a Ruby web framework like [Ruby on Rails](https://rubyonrails.org/) or [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com/). If you link to your GitHub or wherever the code is you may be able to get more specific advice.